# Livewire component not working properly when call from form hide / show?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using the LiveWire Media component.
Here is my component called in blade file.

Below component called on page load.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <livewire:media title="Browse Image" name="media_image_id" type="select" :options="['image']" :selectedMedias="$course->mediaImage ?? null" :unique-key="$unique_key" :table="$table" id="media_image"/>
</div>
```

After that on button click one form opened called testform.
In that form below code is written.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <livewire:media title="Browse Image" name="lesson_media_image_id" type="select" :options="['image']" :selectedMedias="$lesson->mediaImage ?? null" :unique-key="$unique_key" :table="$tab" id="lesson_media_image"/>
</div>
```

Media.blade.php

```
@section('title','Media')
<div>
    <div>
        @foreach($selectedMedias as $selectedMedia)
            <input type="hidden" name="{{$name}}" value="{{$selectedMedia->id}}" id="{{$name}}"/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            @switch($selectedMedia->collection_name)
                                @case('images')
                                <img src="{{$selectedMedia->getUrl()}}" class="img-fluid rounded float-left"
                                     alt="{{$selectedMedia->name}}"
                                     style="max-height: 150px;"/>
                                @break
                            @endswitch
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h6 class="card-title">
                                    <div>{{$selectedMedia->name}}</div>
                                </h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mediaModal-{{$name}}">
        {{$title}}
    </button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="mediaModal-{{$name}}">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-scrollable">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Media Library</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <!-- Nav pills -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-2">
                        @if(in_array('image',$options))
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link {{$options[0]==='image'?'active':''}}" data-toggle="pill"
                                   href="#image-show">
                                    All Images
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#image-upload"
                                   data-url="{{route('media.upload',['uniqueKey' => $uniqueKey,'table'=>$table,'tenant'=>tenantName()])}}">
                                    Upload Image
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        @if(in_array('image',$options))
                            <div class="tab-pane container {{$options[0]==='image'?'active':''}}" id="image-show">
                                <livewire:media.show-images :type="$type" :select="$select" :name="$name"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="image-upload">
                                <livewire:media.upload-images/>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now problem is when on page load component is called modal is open and can select and upload image.
When I comment on page load component at that time I able to active upload button tab, but unable to open or drag and drop image as well as strore in database.
when form is show above component is called modal is also open but when click on upload tab it will show selected but upload form is not become active also image is also not able to select from all images.